# How to trigger my event after other events have completed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I'm using Bootstrap's [button thingy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons)

And I have a custom event attached on the buttons

```
$('.btn').bind('update', function(){
  // here I check if the button has the "Active" class and do something
});

$('.btn').click(function(){
  // here I trigger my event
  $(this).trigger('update');
});
```

So Bootstrap's click event should add the active class, but it appears it does so after my event, so my active class does not appear to be set within my event :|

Can I somehow run my click event after bootstrap's click event?

---

test:

http://jsfiddle.net/V55ZH/

As you can see the alert fires before the "Active" class is being set, so before Bootstrap's click event runs (the class state is unreliable to me from my event)

Comment: missing `'` on your selectors

Comment: can you just find where bootstrap's `onClick` is happening and add to that block?

Comment: you mean liek changing bootstrap.js and loose my changes if I update bootstrap? eww

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From a quick glance at bootstrap's JS code (https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-button.js) - You can notice that the event is actually attached not directly on the button element, rather on it's container. What actually happens in your example is that bootstrap wraps the buttons with a container DIV of class "btn-group" with an attribute data-toggle="buttons-checkbox". Once clicked the event handler is fired and you can get the clicked button using the event object.

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button class="btn active">A</button>
  <button class="btn active">B</button>
  <button class="btn active">C</button>
  <button class="btn">D</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '[data-toggle^=button]', function(e) {
      var btn = $(e.target);
      if (btn.hasClass('btn')) {
          alert(btn.hasClass('active'));
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: -1 Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of 
the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Indeed; the answer needs to be posted on stackoverflow, so that it remains accessible.